# Java not whole object returned?

Tags: java, jsf

I am developing JSF but the problem is in the java I believe. Ok so I have a table with requests, when I press the id of the request that is sent to the reviewRequest page with:

```
 <h:inputHidden id="id" value="#{requestClass.requestID}" />
```

Now that's working because I load the request details on next page (by taking ID and retrieving object from database). now when I modify the object from reviewRequest and accept, it says it is stored successfully. I then view the same page again from table I click the request id and there it goes bang nullpointerexception. When it is loading the object this time, it pass the id to retrieve method then it only returns the change but not the whole object details like name, contacts, etc. only that the user of type x submitted modification y. retrieve method from DB works for sure because all over the app it is working correctly. Any idea? some of the code below for illustration:

```
public void callIsValidUser(){
     boolean holder = isValidUser();
     if(holder == true){
         rsvIns = loadDetails();
     }else{
          try{

     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("pending.xhtml");
         }catch(IOException ioe){
             System.err.print(ioe);
         }
     }
 }
```

the method above works the first time but not after modification. in isValid():

```
public boolean isValidUser(){

    boolean valid = false;
    try{
       rsvLocal = oracleRsv.retrieveReservation(id);
       String reqDivHead = rsvLocal.rdhUser.getUserID();
       //rsvLocal.rdhUser.getUserResponse();
       String supervisor = rsvLocal.sUser.getUserID();           
       String divHead = rsvLocal.dhUser.getUserID();          
       String currentUser = System.getProperty("user.name");  
         .....
```

now when I inspect the rsvLocal in netbeans debug mode, i see that rdhUser.response holds the modification I entered but all rest is null. How can this happen? how can some data be retrieved from object? 
Thanks,

Comment: BTW: Whatever you do with the system property `user.name` smells fishy in the JSF context.

Comment: really? it is always working well and the string is an exact match :) I have to do it this way because it is a mechanism of detection that enables me to get rid of login page.

Comment: Then let's hope your code does never hits the internet. This means that the OS-user who started the server is handled differently than John Doe. This might be a backdoor. This might smash multiple concurrent users. This might trash testing ("on my machine it works...") ...

Comment: nah it wont hit the internet at all...only intranet where all users have unique id's which am using to track them.

Comment: I would have created a login page which is most sensible really but my boss said that the bigger boss dont want to waste time logging in! what can i do but comply :P

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you did not load the data at the very beginning. Then JSF created an empty bean and sets the values from the form. Now everything not mentioned in the form (and of course every empty field of the form) contains `null`. This half-baked bean is now stored in the DB *overwriting the complete row*. If you now load the row again you will see what you call "my modifications" but what is the complete content of the DB. Your old data is lost.

The key point is: JSF and the DB-Layers do not deal with "modifications" of individual fields - they handle *complete* entities.

Comment: aha somehow this makes good sense...what's your recommendation?

Comment: You have to adjust your code to always deal with complete entity beans. How to do that depends completely on you code.

Comment: Sorry but I need to clarify. so when am editing the variable rsvinstance.user.userresponse(true) I should then write all the data such as name, dob, etc again in the same place?